# How to download privat pastebin paste via curl (cmd/bat)

Tags: batch-file, curl, cmd, paste, pastebin

Hey i want to download my private paste via a batch/cmd file with using curl as it is privat i have to login with my api dev key but this does not work output is some html code

I already tried but it did not worked i dont know why.

`curl -s -o sdggsd.txt -d "api_dev_key=key" https://pastebin.com/raw/link`

Edit : Now I also tried this but it says no url specified.

```
curl -d 'api_dev_key=key' -d 'api_user_name=name' -d 'api_user_password=pass' -o sdggsd.txt "https://pastebin.com/raw/url"
```

Edit : So this code works but it outputs in the file only html code :( not the code that is on the website

```
curl -o st.txt -d 'api_dev_key=key' -d 'api_user_name=user' -d 'api_user_password=pass' https://pastebin.com/raw/url
```

st.txt file result for command :

```
curl -o st.txt -d 'api_dev_key=key' -d 'api_user_name=user' -d 'api_user_password=pass' "https://pastebin.com/raw/url"
```

result in st.txt :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.75, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />
        <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-S72LBY47R8"></script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());
      gtag('config', "G-S72LBY47R8");
    </script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Pastebin.com - Bad Request (#400)</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="description" content="Pastebin.com is the number one paste tool since 2002. Pastebin is a website where you can store text online for a set period of time." />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Pastebin.com is the number one paste tool since 2002. Pastebin is a website where you can store text online for a set period of time." />
            <meta property="fb:app_id" content="231493360234820" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Pastebin.com - Bad Request (#400)" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://pastebin.com/raw/url" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://pastebin.com/i/facebook.png" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Pastebin" />
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="jkUAIOE8owUXu8UXIhRLB9oHJsWBfOgJbZzncqHoF4A" />
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://pastebin.com/raw/url" />
        <meta name="csrf-param" content="_csrf-frontend">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="BBCH6PRTqsfFEJnQk2n_8j6Jfe7FUMIOP34snpj8SidSQe69sD_JiapZzZX5G8eHDucP24MfqHx7HXWt_pQhRQ==">

<link href="/assets/c80611c4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/assets/a25015e7/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" rel="stylesheet">        
<link href="/themes/pastebin/css/vendors.bundle.css?d9b75a0225d98a07f54f" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/themes/pastebin/css/app.bundle.css?d9b75a0225d98a07f54f" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
<body class="night-auto " data-pr="x2xy94pJ" data-pa="" data-sar="1" data-abd="1" data-bd="1">


<svg style="height: 0; width: 0; position: absolute; visibility: hidden" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <symbol id="add" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024"><path fill="#ccc" d="M512 16C238 16 16 238 16 512s222 496 496 496 496-222 496-496S786 16 512 16z m288 552c0 13.2-10.8 24-24 24h-184v184c0 13.2-10.8 24-24 24h-112c-13.2 0-24-10.8-24-24v-184h-184c-13.2 0-24-10.8-24-24v-112c0-13.2 10.8-24 24-24h184v-184c0-13.2 10.8-24 24-24h112c13.2 0 24 10.8 24 24v184h184c13.2 0 24 10.8 24 24v112z"/></symbol>
    <symbol id="search" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path fill="#ccc" d="M354.2,216c0-38.2-13-70.7-40-97.7c-27-27-59.6-40-97.7-40s-70.7,13-97.7,40s-40,59.6-40,97.7 s13,70.7,40,97.7s59.6,40,97.7,40s70.7-13,97.7-40C340.2,285.8,354.2,253.2,354.2,216z M511.5,472c0,10.2-3.7,19.5-12.1,27.9 c-8.4,8.4-16.8,12.1-27.9,12.1c-11.2,0-20.5-3.7-27.9-12.1L339.3,393.8c-37.2,26.1-78.2,38.2-122.9,38.2 c-29.8,0-57.7-5.6-83.8-16.8c-27-11.2-50.3-27-68.9-46.5s-34.4-42.8-46.5-68.9C6.1,272.8,0.5,244.8,0.5,216s5.6-57.7,16.8-83.8 c11.2-27,27-50.3,46.5-68.9s42.8-34.4,68.9-46.5C159.7,5.6,187.6,0,216.4,0s57.7,5.6,83.8,16.8c27,11.2,50.3,27,68.9,46.5 c18.6,19.5,34.4,42.8,46.5,68.9c11.2,27,16.8,54.9,16.8,83.8c0,44.7-13,85.6-38.2,122.9L499.4,444 C507.8,451.5,511.5,460.8,511.5,472z"/></g></symbol>
</svg>
<div class="wrap">

        
        
<div class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header__container">

                        <div class="header__left">
                <a class="header__logo" href="/">
                    Pastebin                </a>

                <div class="header__links h_1024">
                    
                                        <a href="/doc_api">API</a>
                    <a href="/tools">tools</a>
                    <a href="/faq">faq</a>
                                    </div>

                <a class="header__btn" href="/">
                    paste                </a>

                
                <div class="header__search">
                                            <form id="w0" class="search_form" action="https://pastebin.com/search" method="get">
                            
<input type="text" id="q" class="search_input" name="q" maxlength="128" placeholder="Search...">



                            <button type="submit" class="search_btn"><svg class="icon search"><use xlink:href="#search"></use></svg></button>
                        </form>                                    </div>

            </div>

                        <div class="header__right">

                                    <div class="header_sign">
                        <a href="/login" class="btn-sign sign-in">Login</a>
                        <a href="/signup" class="btn-sign sign-up">Sign up</a>
                    </div>
                
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
        

    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">

                        
                        
                                    
            
            
<div class="page -top -right">

    <div class="content__title">Bad Request (#400)</div>
    <div class="content__text">
        <div class="notice -no-margin">
            Unable to verify your data submission.        </div>
    </div>

</div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>

                                </div>

        <div class="sidebar h_1024">
            



                
    <div class="sidebar__title">
        <a href="/archive">Public Pastes</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="sidebar__menu">

                    <li>
                <a href="/iFuBSXP1">BTC Wallet Credentials have been reset</a>
                <div class="details">
                                            GetText |
                    
                    3 min ago
                    | 0.24 KB                </div>
            </li>
                    <li>
                <a href="/vF3axSgu">Link crash</a>
                <div class="details">
                                            Java |
                    
                    22 min ago
                    | 2.37 KB                </div>
            </li>
                    <li>
                <a href="/gip3QbEX">Untitled</a>
                <div class="details">
                                            Lua |
                    
                    44 min ago
                    | 3.51 KB                </div>
            </li>
                    <li>
                <a href="/LGiNgvMF">Untitled</a>
                <div class="details">
                                            Python |
                    
                    47 min ago
                    | 2.60 KB                </div>
            </li>
                    <li>
                <a href="/jFSDzvks">Dig</a>
                <div class="details">
                                            Lua |
                    
                    1 hour ago
                    | 2.28 KB                </div>
            </li>
                    <li>
                <a href="/fCVJabwN">bot.lua</a>
                <div class="details">
                                            Lua |
                    
                    1 hour ago
                    | 1.27 KB                </div>
            </li>
                    <li>
                <a href="/CX6NWCqD">Quirk Command</a>
                <div class="details">
                                            JavaScript |
                    
                    1 hour ago
                    | 3.30 KB                </div>
            </li>
                    <li>
                <a href="/cua5U8BE">bot.lua</a>
                <div class="details">
                                            Lua |
                    
                    1 hour ago
                    | 1.25 KB                </div>
            </li>
        
    </ul>
            

    <div class="sidebar__sticky -on">
                    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


    
<div class="top-footer">
    <a class="icon-link -size-24-24 -chrome" href="/tools#chrome" title="Google Chrome Extension"></a>
    <a class="icon-link -size-24-24 -firefox" href="/tools#firefox" title="Firefox Extension"></a>
    <a class="icon-link -size-24-24 -iphone" href="/tools#iphone" title="iPhone/iPad Application"></a>
    <a class="icon-link -size-24-24 -windows" href="/tools#windows" title="Windows Desktop Application"></a>
    <a class="icon-link -size-24-24 -android" href="/tools#android" title="Android Application"></a>
    <a class="icon-link -size-24-24 -macos" href="/tools#macos" title="MacOS X Widget"></a>
    <a class="icon-link -size-24-24 -opera" href="/tools#opera" title="Opera Extension"></a>
    <a class="icon-link -size-24-24 -unix" href="/tools#pastebincl" title="Linux Application"></a>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="footer__container">

            <div class="footer__left">
                <a href="/">create new paste</a> <span class="footer__devider">&nbsp;/&nbsp;</span>
                                <a href="/languages">syntax languages</a> <span class="footer__devider">&nbsp;/&nbsp;</span>
                <a href="/archive">archive</a> <span class="footer__devider">&nbsp;/&nbsp;</span>
                <a href="/faq">faq</a> <span class="footer__devider">&nbsp;/&nbsp;</span>
                <a href="/tools">tools</a> <span class="footer__devider">&nbsp;/&nbsp;</span>
                <a href="/night_mode">night mode</a> <span class="footer__devider">&nbsp;/&nbsp;</span>
                <a href="/doc_api">api</a> <span class="footer__devider">&nbsp;/&nbsp;</span>
                <a href="/doc_scraping_api">scraping api</a> <span class="footer__devider">&nbsp;/&nbsp;</span>
                <a href="/news">news</a> <span class="footer__devider">&nbsp;/&nbsp;</span>
                <a href="/pro" class="pro">pro</a>

                <br>
                <a href="/doc_privacy_statement">privacy statement</a> <span class="footer__devider">&nbsp;/&nbsp;</span>
                <a href="/doc_cookies_policy">cookies policy</a> <span class="footer__devider">&nbsp;/&nbsp;</span>
                <a href="/doc_terms_of_service">terms of service</a><sup style="color:#999">updated</sup> <span class="footer__devider">&nbsp;/&nbsp;</span>
                <a href="/doc_security_disclosure">security disclosure</a> <span class="footer__devider">&nbsp;/&nbsp;</span>
                <a href="/dmca">dmca</a> <span class="footer__devider">&nbsp;/&nbsp;</span>
                <a href="/report-abuse">report abuse</a> <span class="footer__devider">&nbsp;/&nbsp;</span>
                <a href="/contact">contact</a>

                <br>

                                
                <br>

                
<span class="footer__bottom h_800">
    By using Pastebin.com you agree to our <a href="/doc_cookies_policy">cookies policy</a> to enhance your experience.
    <br>
    Site design &amp; logo &copy; 2023 Pastebin</span>
            </div>

            <div class="footer__right h_1024">
                                    <a class="icon-link -size-40-40 -facebook-circle" href="https://facebook.com/pastebin" rel="nofollow" title="Like us on Facebook" target="_blank"></a>
                    <a class="icon-link -size-40-40 -twitter-circle" href="https://twitter.com/pastebin" rel="nofollow" title="Follow us on Twitter" target="_blank"></a>
                            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
    


    
<div class="popup-container">

                <div class="popup-box -cookies" data-name="l2c_1">
            We use cookies for various purposes including analytics. By continuing to use Pastebin, you agree to our use of cookies as described in the <a href="/doc_cookies_policy">Cookies Policy</a>.            &nbsp;<span class="cookie-button js-close-cookies">OK, I Understand</span>
        </div>
    
                <div class="popup-box -pro" data-name="l2c_2_pg">
            <div class="pro-promo-img">
                <a href="/signup">
                    <img src="/themes/pastebin/img/hello.png" alt=""/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="pro-promo-text">
                Not a member of Pastebin yet?<br/>
                <a href="/signup"><b>Sign Up</b></a>, it unlocks many cool features!            </div>
            <div class="close js-close-pro-guest" title="Close Me">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    
    
    
</div>
    

<span class="cd-top"></span>

<script src="/assets/9ce1885/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/f04f76b8/yii.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/a25015e7/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>
<script>
    const POST_EXPIRATION_NEVER = 'N';
    const POST_EXPIRATION_BURN = 'B';
    const POST_STATUS_PUBLIC = '0';
    const POST_STATUS_UNLISTED = '1';
</script>
<script src="/themes/pastebin/js/vendors.bundle.js?d9b75a0225d98a07f54f"></script>
<script src="/themes/pastebin/js/app.bundle.js?d9b75a0225d98a07f54f"></script>
```

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? https://pastebin.com/doc_api#13 You have to create a separate API user key and use that if you want to download the raw text of private pastes.

Comment: yep already tried that but now im using github so its fine

Answer (score 0):

You need to curl the raw text, not the site. A raw paste (or github file) will be only the text, no tags.

Comment: i am curling the raw text https://pastebin.com/raw/ like theres the raw but it still outputs the html code

Comment: Check inspect element, there might be some unnessary code. Could you also post the result of "st.txt"?

Comment: posted st.txt result also could not find any unnessary code it doesnt even download anything of the correct raw paste sorry for my bad english

Comment: After doing some research: pastebin raw has extra HTML padding. I suggest using GitHub raw, or, if you don't want to wait 5 minutes for a cache, paste the code into `index.html` and host a static site using [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/).

Comment: I will try my luck with github raw but idk how github works but thanks

Comment: worked instantly well thanks lmao

Comment: No problem, remember it takes 5 minutes to cache so if you change it you'll have to wait 5 minutes

Comment: what do you mean with 5 minutes to cache?

Comment: After an edit on the original file, the raw will take 5 minutes to update